# Prompt user for save path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, save

This function uses package: 
https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor

I am trying to have this function prompt the user for a save path for the file that's being downloaded.

Currently this is what it tells me when the function is called:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express.mp4' is denied.

```
protected void SaveVideo_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var RowID = e.CommandArgument;
        int submissionIDColumn = Convert.ToInt32(RowID);
        var data = ParentSelect.DataKeys[submissionIDColumn]["SubmissionID"].ToString();
        int ParseDataInt = Convert.ToInt32(data);
        var query = (from r in dbContext.Mains
                     where r.SubmissionID.Equals(ParseDataInt)
                     select r);
        foreach (var record in query)
        {
            var VideoID = record.VideoUrl.FirstOrDefault();

            var link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Mfb9gcB3lM";
            IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(link);
            VideoInfo video = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);

            if (video.RequiresDecryption)
            {
                DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
            }
            string savePath =
                    Path.Combine(
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                        Path.ChangeExtension("myVideo", video.VideoExtension));
            var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(video, video.VideoExtension); 
            videoDownloader.Execute();
        }
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to get was how could I get a "save path" from users. Apparently getting any local machine information from users concerning local file structure is a security flaw, and browsers specifically implement functionality to prevent this information from being acquired.